# T-SQL Select Join 3 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I'm currently working on a select query in T-SQL on SQL Server 2012. It's a complex query, I want to query a list from 3 tables. The result should look something like this:

**Desired Output:**

```
ProjectId |    Title    | Manager   | Contact   | StatusId 
----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+-----------
1         |   projectX  |   1123    |  4453     |  1 
2         |   projectY  |   2245    |  5567     |  1
3         |   projectZ  |   3335    |  8899     |  1
```

My 3 Tables:
1) **Project:** ProjectId, ProjectDataId, MemberVersionId 
2) **ProjectData:** ProjectDataId, Title, StatusId 
3) **Members:** MemberId, MemberVersionId, MemberTypeId, EmployeeId

The tricky part is, to implement versioning. Thus, over time the project Members can change, and it should always be possible to return to a previous version, that's why I use *MemberVersionId* as a foreign key inbetween *Project* and *Members*. The tables Project and ProjectData a linked with ProjectDataId.

Hence, 1 Project has 1 OfferData and 1 Project has N Members.

Some sample data:
*Project*

```
ProjectId | ProjectDataId | MemberVersionId | 
----------+---------------+-----------------+
1         |   2           |   1             | 
2         |   3           |   1             |
3         |   4           |   1             |
```

*ProjectData*

```
ProjectDataId |    Title    | StatusId 
--------------+-------------+-----------
2             |   projectX  |  1 
3             |   projectY  |  1
4             |   projectZ  |  1
```

*Members:* MemberTypeId 1 = Manager, MemberTypeId 2 = Contact, 3 = Other

```
MemberId | MemberVersionId | MemberTypeId | EmployeeId | 
---------+-----------------+--------------+------------+
1        |   1             |   1          |  1123      | 
2        |   1             |   2          |  4453      |
3        |   1             |   3          |  9999      |
4        |   2             |   1          |  2245      | 
5        |   2             |   2          |  5567      | 
6        |   2             |   3          |  9999      | 
7        |   3             |   1          |  3335      | 
8        |   3             |   2          |  8899      | 
9        |   3             |   3          |  9999      |
```

My current query looks like this:

```
SELECT ProjectId, Title, EmployeeId AS Manager, EmployeeId AS Contact, StatusId
FROM [MySchema].[Project] a,
     [MySchema].[ProjectData] b,
     [MySchema].[Members] c
WHERE a.ProjectDataId = b.ProjectDataId
  AND a.MemberVersionId = c.MemberVersionId
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work yet. Do you know how to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Add desired output

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read an maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT 
    p.ProjectId, 
    pd.Title, 
    mm.EmployeeId AS Manager, 
    mc.EmployeeId AS Contact, 
    pd.StatusId
FROM 
    [MySchema].[Project] p
    INNER JOIN [MySchema].[ProjectData] pd ON pd.ProjectDataId = p.ProjectDataId
    INNER JOIN [MySchema].[Members] mm ON mm.MemberVersionId = p.MemberVersionId AND mm.MemberTypeId = 1
    INNER JOIN [MySchema].[Members] mc ON mc.MemberVersionId = p.MemberVersionId AND mc.MemberTypeId = 2;
```

Comment: Best answer. Easy to read, proper joins, appropriate table aliases.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
    SELECT ProjectId, Title, C.EmployeeId AS Manager, d.EmployeeId AS Contact, StatusId
FROM [MySchema].[Project] a
INNER JOIN    [MySchema].[ProjectData] b ON A.ProjectDataId=B.ProjectDataId
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM [MySchema].[Members] WHERE MemberTypeID=1) c ON a.MemberVersionId=c.MemberVersionId  
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT * FROM [MySchema].[Members] WHERE MemberTypeID=2)  d ON a.MemberVersionId=d.MemberVersionId
```

Answer (score 3):

You must select members two times, one for the manager and another for contact:

```
SELECT ProjectId, Title, m.EmployeeId AS Manager, c.EmployeeId AS 
    Contact, StatusId
FROM [MySchema].[Project] a,
  [MySchema].[ProjectData] b,
  [MySchema].[Members] m
  [MySchema].[Members] c
WHERE a.ProjectDataId = b.ProjectDataId
  AND a.MemberVersionId = m.MemberVersionId and m.MemberTypeId = 1
  AND a.MemberVersionId = c.MemberVersionId and c.MemberTypeId = 2
```

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
 SELECT ProjectId, Title, cmanager.EmployeeId AS Manager, ccon.EmployeeId AS 
 Contact, StatusId
 from  [MySchema].[ProjectData] b
 inner join [MySchema].[Project] a on b.ProjectDataId=a.ProjectDataId
 left join [MySchema].[Members] cmanager on cmanager.MemberVersionId = 
  a.MemberVersionId and cmanager.MemberTypeId=1
 left join [MySchema].[Members] ccon on ccon.MemberVersionId = 
 a.MemberVersionId and ccon.MemberTypeId=2
```

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution to your problem would be introducing additional field to `Project` table. You'd either call it `LatestMemberVersion` (int, holds the currently highest MemberVersionId), which would by the most up to date version of the relationship, your you can add even simpler `IsLatestMemberVersion` (bit, holds 1 if the record is the latest/active). You can compute both of them using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER` statement.

Then, the query would change to:

```
SELECT ProjectId, Title, EmployeeId AS Manager, EmployeeId AS Contact, StatusId
FROM [MySchema].[Project] a,
     [MySchema].[ProjectData] b ON a.ProjectDataId = b.ProjectDataId
     [MySchema].[Members] c ON a.MemberVersionId = c.MemberVersionId
WHERE 
a.[IsLatestMemberVersion] = 1 -- alternative is a.[LatestMemberVersion] = a.[MemberVersionId]
```

Additionally, there are two more things you can try:

1. you might want to borrow ideas from data warehousing, namely you will want to have combination of Slowly Changing Dimension Type 1 and 2
2. you can try to use SQL Server features, such as Change Data Tracking. But I have no experience with that, so it's possible it'll lead to nowhere.

And one last piece of advice, if you can, never write join conditions into the WHERE clause. It is not readable and can lead to problems when you suddenly change JOIN to LEFT JOIN. Microsoft itself recommends using `ON` instead of `WHERE` when applicable.